# Bash string close match

Tags: regex, string, bash

I'm trying to find a good reliable way to compare multiple strings. The source can't produce 100% accurate results. Most of these are from the same source data, but most are off by one or more characters.
Sample Source Data:

```
LWE5345
LWF5345
PSE5345
VMA5345
VMF5345
VMK5345
VSK5345
VV534S
VVE5345
VVF5345
VVG5345
VVK5345
VL5345
VL534
VW534S
VWA5344
```

Expected Result (sample format but open to ideas)

Strings with 7 Matching characters

```
....
```

Strings with 6 Matching characters

```
LWE5345 LWF5345
VMA5345 VMF5345 
....
```

Strings with 5 Matching characters

```
VL5345 VL534 WVL534
```

Comment: Sounds like you might like to compute the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the strings and accept any whose distance is <=2.

Comment: Do you know what they have in common like you are looking for `534`?

Comment: No specific patterns between the strings. Just looking for closely matched strings.